# Backup and restore / Copy user profile Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, user-profiles

how can I backup / restore user profile with user settings in windows 8.1? Unfortunately windows 8 does not support export in Easy Transfer. right now I have to copy manually user files and restore all settings one by one. Do you know any automated procedure to copy profile?

Comment: W.E.T. was basically killed with Windows 8.  Use an MS account and it'll sync your settings between computers.  Put your documents in OneDrive and it'll be available on all computers you log into using your MS account, etc. You get where this is going yet? ;)

Comment: how about firefox and outlook settings? will one drive sync all these settings/files too?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [USMT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824873.aspx) (user state migration tool) to move profiles. This tool will allow you to do this even without logging into the computer interactively.  There's instructions for computer in domain and not joined to a domain.  Cheers!

Comment: While I upvoted because it's the only method made for this, this answer leaves a lot to be desired, such as the actual steps required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "File History" feature of Windows 8.1?. Hopefully, it take backup of your Libraries, Contacts, Favorites to an external drive or network storage location

Go to Control Panel > File History. If this option is not turned on, then plug a USB or network storage and click on "Turn On". Now, customize your backup settings using the options available in the left pane of the "File History" window. As per the schedule, all the backup will be saved to the USB or network storage location.

To restore, use Control Panel > Recovery option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont think that file history restores firefox and outlook settings... it only restores raw files.